# Function definition in parameter of class extension?

Tags: scala, inheritance, subclass

In [this part of Play Framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Security$$AuthenticatedBuilder$), I found the following line of code:

```
object Authenticated extends AuthenticatedBuilder(req => getUserFromRequest(req))
```

The part that puzzles me is `eq => getUserFromRequest(req))`. Why is there a function definition in the superclass' parameters? Isn't it supposed to hold only the parameters from the superclass that should be inherited by the subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala, functions are first-class elements, which means they can be passed as parameters and returned as function results.

From the [source file](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.18/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Security.scala) we see that `AuthenticatedBuilder` requires two constructor parameters, both of them functions.

```
class AuthenticatedBuilder[U](userinfo       : RequestHeader => Option[U]
                             ,onUnauthorized : RequestHeader => Result =
                   _ => Unauthorized(views.html.defaultpages.unauthorized())
                             ) extends ActionBuilder[...] { ...
```

In the example you've quoted there is only one parameter provided because the 2nd parameter has a default value.

Comment: Got it. I mistakenly thought that you couldn't give any concrete arguments to the class from which you where inheriting, only parameters. That is, I thought that this wasn't legal: `class Person (name: String, age: Int); object Bobby extends Person("Bobby", 12)`.